# iPhone Button Selected State

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am created two buttons that are right next to each other to mimic a segmented control.  I am doing this to customize the appearance beyond what the UIKit allows.  I decided to use the selected property to keep a button pressed.  I have two images that one for each state normal and selected.

The problem is that when I select a button, the button highlights and turns dark, because of the hightlight state.  I decided to use the selected image for the highlight state too, but it flashes, any ideas or suggestions.

```
- (void)leftSegmentPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "selected" button, disable it and manually switch the image for the state.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [rightSegmentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightSegmentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [leftSegmentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftSegmentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}

- (void)leftSegmentPressed:(id)sender
{
    sender.enabled = NO;
    rightSegmentButton.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)rightSegmentPressed:(id)sender
{
    sender.enabled = NO;
    leftSegmentButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this approach?

Comment: This worked okay, I also used the selected image for the highlighted state as well to avoid a slight delay

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the image you given is in your `Bundle` or check image name you given is in `lower case` or not. Then write like

```
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected2.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

button1.tag = 1;
button2.tag = 2;

[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

in your button event method

```
-(void)buttonSelected:(id)sender {
    if([sender tag] == 1) {
        button1.selected = YES;
        button2.selected = NO;
    } else {
         button1.selected = NO;
         button2.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];

This will prevent the flicker.

Comment: Not sure, when you say, there is a delay. Unless the images you are using are large, there should not be a delay. Can you please try with very small images. I have just created a project to simulate your problem and it works fine with me. Any ways, Best of luck and hope you find a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *yourButton1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
yourButton1.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[yourButton1 setTitle:@"Left" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
yourButton1.tag = 1;
[yourButton1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];    

UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourNormalImage.png"];// set normal image 
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[yourButton1 setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourSelectedImage.png"];// set selected image
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[yourButton1 setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[yourButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(leftSegmentPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:yourButton1];
```

do same for another second button.

and in action method set bellow code..

```
- (void)leftSegmentPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnTemp = (UIBUtton *)sender;
    if (btnTemp.tag == 1) {
        [yourButton1 setSelected:YES];
        [yourButton2 setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
        [yourButton1 setSelected:NO];
        [yourButton2 setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```